# Convertir window.innerWidth de Jquery a Javascript Puro

Tags: javascript, jquery

Luego de buscar por horas algo que lograra agregar la clase `btn-sm` a mis botones si se accedia desde un celular, encontré este código Jquery que me funcionó:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 
    if(window.innerWidth < 768){
        $('.btn').addClass('btn-sm');
    }
 
});
```

Francamente evito usar Jquery y siento que al usar dicho código mi sitio tarda un poco más en cargar.
Traté de convertirlo a Javascript puro con mis pocos conocimientos y con esta [guía](https://webdeasy.de/en/jquery-to-javascript/):

```
function ready (fn) {
  if(window.innerWidth < 768){
    document.querySelector('.btn').classList.add('btn-sm');
    }
}
```

Pero no funciona, no se agrega la clase `btn-sm` a los botones. ¿Qué está mal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) devuevel solo el primer elemento encontrado.

Necesitas utilizar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) para obtener todos.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function ready() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 1024) {
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(e => e.classList.add('btn-sm'));
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll('.btn').forEach(e => e.classList.remove('btn-sm'));
  }
}
window.addEventListener('resize', ready);
ready();
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: blue;
}

.btn.btn-sm {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Btn 1</button>
<button class="btn">Btn 2</button>
<button class="btn">Btn 3</button>
```

Comment: Entiendo, ya lo probé pero de igual forma no funciona:( no se aplica la clase, estoy usando bootstrap 5

Comment: @NotoriusSha, acabo de agregar un ejemplo funcional, espero que te sirva.

Comment: muchas graciaaaas! Funciona perfecto.